# How to print the first letter from a list of random names

Tags: python

How to print the first letter from a list of random names?
This is what I have done so far and I can print the names randomly but need to print the first letter and not the whole name.

```
import random

names = ['Ed Sheeran', 'Beyonce', 'Adele', 'Rhianna']
secure_random = random.SystemRandom()
print(secure_random.choice (names))
```

Comment: `print(secure_random.choice(names)[0])` ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use:

```
print(random.choice(names)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Randomize the list and then print the first character-

```
import random
names = ['Ed Sheeran', 'Beyonce', 'Adele', 'Rhianna']
random_names = random.sample(names, len(names))
#If you are okay with mutating the original list then look into "shuffle"
for name in random_names:
    print(name[0])
```

Output-

```
E
R
A
B
```

Comment: It probably will work, but I would recommend not to use such non intuitive names for variables like `_`. It is well received by most of programmers if variable is self-explanatory like in this case `name` :-)

Comment: @Paradowski sorry about that....happened because of muscle memory....have been dealing with a lot of useless contents in iterables.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quickie because this is that I think you're looking for. You can put them into a string on one line using

```
print(" ".join((f[0] for f in random.shuffle(names)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Shuffle the array, and print the first letter of each

```
 names_copy = list(names)
 shuffled_names = random.shuffle(names_copy)
 first_letters = [name[0] for name in shuffled_names]
```